# Why .then(resolveCallback, rejectCallback) behaving differently from .then(resolveCallback).catch(rejectCallback) in polyfill of Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was writing polyfill for Promise.race() method using the below code snippet.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('promise resolved');
});

const promise2 = Promise.resolve('promise2 resolved');

function raceCopy(promises) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    for (var index = 0; index < promises.length; index++) {
        Promise.resolve(promises[index])
          .then(resolve)
          .catch(reject);
    }
  });
}

raceCopy([Promise.reject('copy rejected'), promise, promise2])
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

But instead of giving the error "copy rejected" in the console, it is showing "promise resolved". I do not understand How and Why it is working like this?

**What I tried?**

1. I used the existing Promise.race() API, and it is giving me the correct result "copy rejected".

```
Promise.race([Promise.reject('copy rejected'), promise, promise2])
 .then((response) => console.log(response))
 .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

2. Second, I changed the implementation of the `raceCopy()`. Something like this,

```
function raceCopy(promises) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    for (var index = 0; index < promises.length; index++) {
      Promise.resolve(promises[index]).then(resolve, reject);
    }
  });
}
```

And It is also giving the correct result.

**What I'm not understanding?**
If all the implementations are the same then Why are the results not the same for all? What am I missing here?

Comment: `Promise.resolve` doesn't necesseraly means success. Try running `Promise.resolve(Promise.reject("test")).catch((e) => console.error(e));` and you'll see :)

Comment: Related: [the difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

I've done some tests and found interesting results. Please be aware that this is just something I found out doing tests, so it might be not 100% accurate; a deep dive into the Ecmascript documentation would be more correct for sure.

Basically, the reason that your original code doesn't work is because of the chaining of `.then` and `.catch`.
It is because of how microtasks are queued in this situation. Let's show an example using the following input:

```js
var promises = [Promise.reject('rejected'), Promise.resolve('resolved')];
```

if in your code you use chaining, this is the result:

```js
Promise.resolve(promises[index])
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject)

/*
-----------------------
Microtask queue
-----------------------
- .then of index 0, then enqueue the catch
- .then of index 1 (which resolve the promises)
- .catch of index 0 (which gets ignored)

------------------------------------------------------------
If we reverse the chaining
*/

Promise.resolve(promises[index])
    .catch(reject)
    .then(resolve)

/*
-----------------------
Microtask queue
-----------------------
- .catch of index 0 (which reject the promises) and don't enqueue following .then
- .then of index 1 (which gets ignored)

*/
```

The first `.catch` ends up at the end of the microtask queue because it was enqueued in the first microtask, while the other `.then` are all enqueued in the main task at the very beginning.

This is just speculation, but I think that it works this way to allow for a single `.catch` to catch errors even if there are multiple `.then` before it.

The correct way to fix it is probably the one you already found in your last example. By only using one `.then` you are only queueing one microtask and it will handle it in the correct way.

Comment: Yeah! I also think this works somewhat this way. As I changed the `catch` and `then` order in the first code snippet of the above question and now I think, it is queueing all the `catch` first and then `then`. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You're welcome :) If you think this answers your question, you can mark this as the answer (click on the icon on the left of the text)

Comment: Hey @Drago96, on changing the order of `then` and `catch` we are getting the result for the above code snippet. But if we will change the position of `Promise.reject()` in the argument we are passing to `raceCopy()` function, something like this `[1st ele, 2nd ele, Promise.reject()]`. Then again we will not get right result.

So, I think `.then(cb1, cb2)` is only way to go.